# Can I add condition with spring data standard interface methods

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Can I add condition to provided interface method like "findAll" of spring data? For example, if the table has columns "name" and "deleted" - I can create a query as`findByNameAndDeletedIsNull` which will give all names which have not been deleted. I tried "findAllAndDeletedIsNull" but this does not work - is this possible?
I know it can be achieved with @query, but was curios as how can we augment the standard methods with conditions.

Comment: I answered the best I could from your question - if you want to compose a specific query via a method name, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, there's a specific way to name the method to have it parsed into the correct SQL. Look at this section: [Spring Data JPA reference - query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).

If you have the query ready, you can easily reverse-engineer which method name may help you get the same result. You can compose quite complex queries by building up from those foundation bricks. However, you cannot just create a string representation of the "where" clause as a named method.

From the document, if you want to get all records where a field is null:

```
IsNull  |   findByAgeIsNull  | … where x.age is null
```

will mean a method name such as *findByDeletedIsNull*.

Answer (score 2):

You can do "findByDeletedIsNull"

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) for more info on what key words can be used in a method name.